# Why am I getting 404 status on running a simple spring boot gradle project?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, gradle

I am new to spring-boot. I have created a simple spring-boot version 2.2.6 project with gradle build. I have created a welcome jsp just to print a header. I get 404 status when i run it on my server with http://localhost:8081/welcome.html Following is my build.gradle, application class, controller class and application.properties file:

```
//build.gradle    
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.2.6.RELEASE'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.9.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
    }

    group = 'com.banuprojects'
    version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
    sourceCompatibility = '11'

    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
        implementation 'org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-jasper'
        implementation 'javax.servlet:jstl'
        testImplementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test') {
            exclude group: 'org.junit.vintage', module: 'junit-vintage-engine'
        }
    }

    test {
        useJUnitPlatform()
    }

//application class
        package com.banuprojects.lmsdemo;

    import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
    import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

    @SpringBootApplication
    public class LmsdemoApplication {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            SpringApplication.run(LmsdemoApplication.class, args);
        }

    }

    //controller class
        package com.banuprojects.lmsdemo;

        import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
        import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
        import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

        @Controller
        public class TestController {

            @RequestMapping("/welcome.html")
            public ModelAndView firstPage() {
                return new ModelAndView("welcome");
            }

        }

//application.properties
        spring.mvc.view.prefix:/WEB-INF/jsp/
        spring.mvc.view.suffix:.jsp
```

I am not sure where I have one wrong with the implementation. Any help will be appreciated.
Thank you

Comment: You can share application properties file also

Comment: Can you remove `.html` and leave it as `/welcome` on the `@Controller` and just visit `/welcome.jsp`?

Comment: @HasanCanSaral IF they change it to `/welcome`, how will that match `/welcome.jsp`?

Comment: Please check for property: spring.servlet.context-path, if it is configured you need to pass that value after the port number

Comment: @AmanGarg I have shared my application.properties file in the above code. Also I will try removing .html from Controller method.

Comment: @AmanGarg I have not changed the project to be dynamic web project, so I have not specified any context-path. So please let me know if I will find a context-path in this case?

Comment: @HasanCanSaral I tried removing .html from my controller method but that did not help.

Comment: I didn’t see the port in the application property file and default port is 8080.  How are you changing the port ?

Comment: Well thanks for the comment, I just realized that's the issue while connecting. Thank you for all your input @AmanGarg

Comment: @Fouziya, please upvote ans, is this is resolved

Answer (score 0):

As discussed over the comments. After seeing the application properties file, found that wrong port was passed in the URL.
No other technical error found.